# Does exists auto documentation for eclipse CDT?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I'm searching some plugin for eclipse CDT similar to Atomineer utils. This tool would know / read a method signature (or a class or a property) in c++, read method name and parameters and insert the skeleton of the comment block.

Does exists this tool?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl) for that purpose. CDT has a little support of Doxygen-style documenting, particularly it can generate skeleton comments for functions.

To enable it proceed through **Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor** and select *Doxygen* in **Documentation tool comments**.

Comment: That one is what I'm using now, but the way it generates the comments cannot (AFAIK) be edited. Exists a way to edit the comments templates of the Doxygen tool?